# Pointer to a char array prints out array elements instead of address of the first element?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

If I remember correctly, in class I learned that setting a pointer to an array sets the pointer to hold the address of the first element of that array.

```
int main() {
char str1[5] = {'j', 'h', 'i', 'o', '\0'};
cout << str1 << endl;
char *a=str1;
cout << a << endl;
}
```

However, the following code prints out 'jhio', instead of the memory address of j? Why is that?

Comment: `operator<<` for `char *` is overloaded to print out the characters being pointed to

Answer (score 3):

The `operator <<` is overloaded for many types. For the type `char *` it outputs the string pointed to by the pointer. If you want to output the address stored in the pointer you should write

```
cout << ( void * )a << endl;
```

or

```
cout << static_cast<void *>( a ) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

str1's type degrades to char*, which is a C style string which amounts to the same call as `cout << "hello world"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char str1[5] = {'j', 'h', 'i', 'o', '\0'};
cout << str1 << endl;
char *a=&str1[0];
cout << &a << endl;
```

operator "<<" in cout, It takes a pointer to the beginning of the line

Answer (score 0):

Writing `cout << a << endl;` will print out the values stored at that target. If you want to print the ADDRESS of the pointer, you use the `&`, which is commonly seen in pass-by-reference to get the address of the pointer. This would look like: `cout << &a << endl;`.